# Flutter: dynamic dialog size with image inside

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an image that I show inside a dialog when I tap on it showing this:

[image]

> NOTE: the example image shouldn't have the white gaps.

The code is this:

```
Widget _imageDialog() {
    return Dialog(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.9,
          heightFactor: 0.9,
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: myRent['image'],
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => _errorImage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it always leaves gaps because the size of the dialog is not dynamic. How could I set the maximum size for both height and width and leave a minimum dynamic size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came without looking for it. I was implementing a library to display unique platform widgets for Android and iOS:

https://github.com/stryder-dev/flutter_platform_widgets

```
_imageDialog() async {
    await showPlatformDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.9,
          heightFactor: 0.9,
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: myRent['image'],
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => _errorImage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The original code doesn't change that much, just the wrapper, but the result is this:

https://ibb.co/bWdbZ56

https://ibb.co/gT7xPb4

https://ibb.co/pWJQtjY (wide screen)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code :
**EDIT:** added the width an height as dynamic:

```
Widget _imageDialog() {
MediaQueryData _queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
 double _height = _queryData.size.height / 100.0;
double _width = _queryData.size.width / 100.0;
      return SimpleDialog(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: _width*50,
            height: _height*20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .accentColor
                  .withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              width: _width*50,
              height: _height*20,
              imageUrl: myRent['image'],
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => _errorImage(),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text("cancel"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2),
        ],
      );
    }
```

you can set the width and the height as you wish according to your app sizes

Comment: sorry but that's not respecting the image size. First, it has a fixed size showing always a square image and second, it uses a BoxFit.cover when it needs to be .contain to display the full image

Comment: firstly , the boxfit.cover or .contain is related with the programmer needs and prefferences and this is not a problem, for the fixed size as i said you can set it as the screen width and height by using   MediaQueryData _queryData = MediaQuery.of(this._context);
    _height = _queryData.size.height / 100.0; 
i will edit the answer now

Comment: Sorry but still not taking the image size. The max size can be either widthFactor: 0.9 or heightFactor: 0.9. If it takes less that, the dialog should adapt to the image

Comment: Following my image example the white gaps should be remove but it should take that max width

Comment: why do you need the full size of image at all ? it is related with the screen width and height not with the image source resolution , already the .contain takes the image as its default aspect ratio , you can set the width of showed image by modifiing the _width variable taking care of screen width i wish this will help you

Comment: That's correct. The important things here are the screen size and the image proportions but when I try your example the image looks way too small: https://i.ibb.co/j8G5L0n/Screenshot-1602866951.png.  Being wider than taller it should take the full width. The image as you can see is big enough: https://cdn.certicalia.com/images/postAnchoCompeto/4946-alquilar-vacaciones.jpg

Comment: can you please add number more than 50 and 20 to your width: _width*50,
              height: _height*20, ? can you try a bigger numbers ?

Comment: The image gets bigger but there is always a blue gap

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: please change the color of blue gap inside the solution code  BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .accentColor
                  .withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
change it to white or what ever

Comment: or please just make it as .cover

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you understood the main point of the question. I don't need to make any background transparent or use a cover fit. The image dialog has to be responsive and take the image size without gaps, showing it completely

Comment: this is related with main flutter library dealing with images , too simple, .contain keep the aspect ratio, .cover cover the container width and height and the photo trimmed as these container width and height i hope this get the reslut you wish, if any issue please open an issue at the flutter github page

Comment: that doesn't change the size of the parent container, which is what I need. This is not an issue related to flutter so it shouldn't be created there, just here

Comment: which one doesnt change the file of the parent container ? can you add an edit to your question to know how do you want to see the container ? cany make it on windows paint only?

Comment: any of them. The fit property modifies how the image is displayed on the widget, showing less or more image inside of it but that doesn't modify the real size of the widget. As mentioned, following my original image, the side of the dialog (being and horizontal image) should be as tall as the image, but no more. And that has nothing to do with fit, it should read the image size when the widget loads it